# Incoming calls - Twilio &appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio

I bought a twilio phone number and i would like to setup a voice response with appscript when someone call that number.

Here what i tried, but doesn't work

function doGet() {

var t = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("twiml")

var content = t.evaluate().getContent();

return ContentService.createTextOutput(content).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML)

}

```
<Response> 
  
 <Gather timeout="3" >
    
  <Say voice="man" language="en-us"> Welcome to John auto parts. 

To leave us a message click on 1
To cancel an appointment, press 2.

  </Say>
        
     </Gather>

  <Say voice="man" language="en-us">We didn't receive any anwers from you. Bye !</Say>
  

</Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that MimeType.XML is [no longer available](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228222115?pli=1). The response gets served as plain text. In this case, Twilio will not interpret it correctly and just play back the Say nodes and not generate the post request on user input. It looks like you have to look for an alternative way to create your Twilio webhooks until this is fixed.